# LINQ with EF Core returning duplicated results

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I'm using Entity Framework Core with LINQ to perform some joins, but it's not occur as expected, if select both objects, it returns duplicated, and if i select only person, the phone list is null. I've my object:

```
public class Person{
        private string _Name;
        private string _CompanyTradeName;

        [Key, Column("pID")]
        public uint PersonID { get; set; }

        [Column("pUUID")]
        public Guid PersonUUID { get; set; }

        [Column("pType")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [Column("pCrptName")]
        public string Name { 
            get { return Encryption.DecryptString(_Name); } 
            set { _Name = value; } 
        }

        [Column("pCrptCompanyTradeName")]
        public string CompanyTradeName { 
            get { return (_CompanyTradeName != null) ? Encryption.DecryptString(_CompanyTradeName) : null; }
            set { _CompanyTradeName = value; } 
        }

        [Column("pProfilePicture")]
        public string ProfilePicture { get; set; }

        [Column("pStatus")]
        public bool Status { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<PersonAddress> PersonAddresses { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<PersonDoc> PersonDocs { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<PersonPhone> PersonPhones { get; set; }
}
```

My PersonPhone class:

```
    public class PersonPhone {
        private string _PhoneNumber;

        [Key, Column("ppID")]
        public uint PersonPhoneID { get; set; }

        [Column("ppUUID")]
        public Guid PersonPhoneUUID { get; set; }

        [Column("pID")]
        public uint PersonID { get; set; }

        public PhoneType PhoneTypes { get; set; }

        [Column("ptID")]
        public uint PhoneTypeID { get; set; }

        [Column("ppCrptPhoneNumber")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get { return Encryption.DecryptString(_PhoneNumber); } set { _PhoneNumber = value; } }
    }
```

And i'm trying to return PersonPhone join with Person, but it's returning null:

```
var query = from p in _context.Person
            join pp in _context.PersonPhone on p.PersonID equals pp.PersonID
            select p;

            return Ok(await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync());
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/

Comment: I may be off here, but should `p` not have it's only phone collection in `PersonPhones`...sort of like this `join pp in p.PersonPhones on p.PersonID equals pp.PersonID`. I am just not clear if you want the phone as a result or the person.

Comment: Can you show your PersonPhone class too pls?

Comment: @Serge i've edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try

```
var personId=...
var person= await  _context.Person
             .Where(p=>p.PersonID=personId
             .Include(p=> p.PersonPhones)
             .FirstOrDefaultAsync());
return Ok(person);
```

or if you want just phones

```
var personId=...
var phones = await  _context.PersonPhones
             .Where(p=>p.PersonID=personId
             .Include(p=> p.Person)
             .ToListAsync());
return Ok(phones);
```

but in this case you will have to fix class

```
public class PersonPhone {
        private string _PhoneNumber;

        [Key, Column("ppID")]
        public uint PersonPhoneID { get; set; }


        [Column("ppUUID")]
        public Guid PersonPhoneUUID { get; set; }

        [Column("pID")]
        public uint PersonID { get; set; }

        public virtual Person Person {get; set;}

     .....
    }
```

Comment: But i'm trying to include person phones in the same object as Person, to retrieve all the information. In this case it's not a ICollection<T>?

Comment: @JoãoPedro The way it is now one person can have several one numbers. So one person can have a collection of   PersonPhones

Comment: Is there any way to use LINQ instead of .Include() EF Core functions? Just for curiosity.

Comment: Yes, you can do it the way you did, but if you  have 2 phones, you will have 2 records. So you will have to group to avoid it and the code will be much more complicated.